# Outlook for Mac 2011: is there a way to make this calendaring dialog never appear?

Tags: ms-office, calendar

People often send me Outlook meeting invitations to give me a heads up about events (in this case, mostly video shoots) about which I need to be aware, but which I don't need to attend. For the others, these need to be set as "busy" with reminders. But, as I'm not busy during most of these, and as I don't need to be reminded about them, I modify the meeting settings (as well as set a category for them, so I can differentiate them from real meetings on my calendar).

Whenever I make these sorts of changes, Outlook presents me with this modal dialog, which I find needless and annoying:

[image: Outlook screenshot]

Is there any setting or settings file hack which will make this dialog go away?

Comment: That is a part of Outlook software. There is nothing you can do on the Mac.